# How to get page posts and comments on those posts with app access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to create an app using restfb to get all the posts and comments on those post of any page. I was able to do so using user access token but with app access token I can get only the posts and not comments on them. What could be the reason for this?

Following code worked with user access token to get both posts and comments, but with app token, it doesn't give comments.

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("lockheedmartin", Page.class);
System.out.println(page.getIsVerified());
System.out.println("bio: "+page.getCategory());
int totalResults = 0;
Connection<Post> pageFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection(page.getId() + "/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit", 20));
for (List<Post> feed : pageFeed) {
    totalResults = totalResults + feed.size();
    for (Post post : feed) {
        com.restfb.types.Post.Comments comments = post.getComments();
        if(comments !=null){
            List<Comment> commentList = comments.getData();
            for(Comment comment : commentList){
                System.out.println(comment.getMessage());
            }
        }               
    }           
}
```

So I had to use post's id to fetch the comments.

```
Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("lockheedmartin", Page.class);
int totalResults = 0;
Connection<Post> pageFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection(page.getId() + "/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("limit", 20));
for (List<Post> feed : pageFeed) {
    totalResults = totalResults + feed.size();
    for (Post post : feed) {
        Connection<Comment> comments = facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId()+ "/comments", Comment.class);
        if(comments !=null){
            List<Comment> commentList = comments.getData();
            for(Comment comment : commentList){
                System.out.println(comment.getMessage());
            }
        }               

    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Page is most likely restricted by age or location, so you MUST use a User or Page token. An App Token does not have any relation to a User, so Facebook does not know if you are allowed to see the content.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I can get the comments by post's id though. So what's the point?

Comment: oh, my bad, i did not read carefully - well, in that case, we need more information. please add your code to your question, or at least the exact api calls.

Comment: Done. Please check :)

Comment: please provide the page id and a post id for testing

Comment: "lockheedmartin" is the page name. post id is being fetched here:

`for (Post post : feed) {
        Connection<Comment> comments = facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId()+ "/comments", Comment.class); `

Comment: I can try this in the Graph API Explorer, switch to your application and request the app access token. So you can check if this is working in general. You may change the restfb logging to see, what is sent to Facebook and what you receive. Perhaps this information is useful. IMHO, this should work :)